# Multiple text boxes for AJAX auto complete and name check

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, methods

I'm trying to create a text box that will search a mysql database, provide auto completed text below the text box and then show a confirmation tick or cross to show that the name is already in the database (or not).

I've got it to work with just one text box, but I'd like to add multiple text-boxes on the same page. eg so someone can search for 10 different names, have them all auto completed and then shown with either a green tick or red cross to confirm that they are in the database.

I'm new at this so apologies if it is something obvious that I'm doing wrong!

Thanks in advance.

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function check_username(){

var username = $("#username").val();
if(username.length > 2){

    $.post("username.php", {
        username: $('#username').val(),
    }, function(response){
        $('#Info').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('Info', '"+escape(response)+"')", 450);
    });
    return false;
}
}

function finishAjax(id, response){

  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn(1000);
} 

$(function() {

$( "#username" ).autocomplete(
{
     source:'source.php'    })
});

</script>
```

This the the html textfield:

```
<td><input type="text" id="username" type="text" onblur="return check_username();"/></td>
<td><div id="Info"></div></td>

<td><input type="text" id="username2" type="text" onblur="return check_username2();"/></td>
<td><div id="Info"></div></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$( "input#username,input#username2" ).autocomplete(
```

instead of

```
$( "#username" ).autocomplete(
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's great thanks. Unfortunately I can only get it to work with the auto complete but not with the first part of checking to see if the name is in the database. I've tried changing var username = $("#username").val(); to var username = $("input#username,input#username2").val(); but that doesn't work. I think it might be a problem with where it outputs the message to because at the minute it is looking for the Info id for multiple fields... I'm going to have another play this morning and see if I can figure it out! Thanks again.